# Change value of the variable which previously assigned to another variable

Tags: python

I know the title is confusing, but it's a very simple question:
Given this snippet

```py
@dataclass
class GameData(object):
    board: list

    def get(self):
        return self.board

def assign():
    return [3, 2, 1]

sData = GameData(board=[0,0])
state = sData.get()
state = assign()
```

How can I change the value of the variable board, so that it also changes the value of sData.board

---

To clarify, my program calls `sData.board` a lot. So I think it should be a good idea to assign `state = sData.get()` and only modify the value of `state` variable. Is it possible?

Comment: Short answer: that's not how variables work. Reassigning which value a variable points to doesn't directly affect any other variables that may be pointing to the same value.

Comment: ( You have an extra closing bracket in `GameData(board=[0,0]])` remove it so people can copy/paste and test your code )

Comment: With dataclasses,`why don't you just use `sData.board = [3, 2, 1]` instead of a `get()` function?

Comment: @Kaz my real code actually has 5 variables, not just `board`

Comment: ok, but does this getter have real interest? dataclasses' fields are already read accessible.

Comment: I think it would be cleaner to write `a,b,c,d,e = object.get()` than `a,b,c,d,e = object.a, object.b, object.c, object.d, object.e`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @vcth4nh But in this example you could do `a, b, c, d, e = object.list`... or at least `a, b = object.list`, since it's only two long at first. The bigger question is, do you really need separate local/global variables to refer to all the attributes of your object?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Can you further explain the `object.list`? I tried `a, b, c, d, e = object.list` where the object holds 5 data values but it returns an error.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `object.board`. Have you gone through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) yet? It sounds like you need a more thorough grounding in the basics before you try asking about specifics here.

Answer (score 2):

As CrazyChucky already mentioned, as soon as you execute `state = [3, 2, 1]`, you have a different pointer in the state variable.

You can however operate on the state object directly such as:

```
state[0] = 5
state[1] = 2
state.append(1)
```

This would also influence the board in the sData object.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a list, you can *at best* do something like this:

```
...
state = sData.get()
# state.clear()
# state.extend([3, 2, 1])
state[:] = [3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using = directly will override the whole variable, breaking the reference. You could modify some parts of it:

```py
state[0] = 1
state[1] = 2
state.append(3)
```

Or even better create a setter on your GameData:

```py
@dataclass
class GameData(object):
    board: list

    def get(self):
        return self.board
    def set(self, new_value):
        self.board = new_value

sData.set([1, 2, 3])
```